# On the radius of convergence of solutions of analytic ODE's

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following analytic ODE:
$$\frac{d~x}{d~t} = M(t)\cdot x + u(t),\quad x(0)=v $$ 
where $t$ is a complex variable, $v\in\mathbb{C}^d$, $M(t)$ (resp. $u(t)$) an $d\times d$ matrix (resp. $d\times 1$ matrix) with entries holomorphic functions in an open neighborhood of the origin $0$. By the power series extending of these entries  at $0$, one can immediately obtain a formal solution $$f(t)=\sum_n u_nt^n\in \mathbb{C}^d[[t]]$$ of the given ODE.

My question is as follows: suppose that all entries of $M(t)$ and $u(t)$ converge in the disc $D_\varepsilon$ of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at the origin, then does $f(t)$ converge in the disc $D_\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

For any $r<ε$ the matrix function n $M$ is bounded on $D_r$, the bound is a global Lipschitz constant so that there is a solution for all $|t|\le r$. This means that the solution can be extended to $D_ε$, there are no singularities inside $D_ε$, and its power series must thus have a radius of convergence $\ge ε$.

---

To be more specific, by general properties of a radius of convergence, for any $r<ε$ there is a constant $C>0$ so that 
$$\|M_k\| r^k<C ~\text{ and }~ \|u_k\|r^k<C$$ 
for all $k$ for the power series coefficients of $M(t)$ and $u(t)$.

Now consider the differential equation 
$$
a'(t)=\frac{C(a(t)+1)}{1-\frac{t}r} 
~~\text{with solution}~~
a(t)=(a(0)+1)\left(1-\frac{t}r\right)^{-Cr} -1
$$
The series expansion of the solution has a radius of convergence of $r$. The coefficients satisfy the recurrence equation
$$
t^k:~~(k+1)a_{k+1}=Cr^{-k}\left(\sum_{j=0}^ka_jr^{j}+1\right)
$$

In the given equation the series coefficients for $x(t)$ can be formally constructed via
$$
t^k:~~(k+1)x_{k+1}=\sum_{j=0}^kM_jx_{k-j} + u_k
$$
The norms of these formal coefficients can now be bounded by the recursive inequality
$$
(k+1)\|x_{k+1}\|\le Cr^{-k}\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\|x_{j}\|r^j+1\right)
$$
It follows by induction that if $\|x_j\|\le a_j$ for $j=0,...,k$, then also $\|x_{k+1}\|\le a_{k+1}$, which is insured starting with $a_0=\|v\|=\|x_0\|$. By comparison test, the region of convergence includes the disk of radius $r$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given by
$$
x(t)=e^{M(t)}\,v,
$$
so that the answer is yes.

**Edit**: as noted by Robert Lewis, this is wrong, unless $M$ is a constant matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to consider a wilder situation. I think the answer is still yes for the similar reason as you provided. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: The formula for the solution will have a second term, but the conclusion will be the same.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Unless $M(t) = M \cdot t$, $x(t) = e^{M(t)}v$ is ***not*** in general a solution of $\dot x = M(t)x$.  In this case, the entries of $M(t)$ are general holomorphic functions of $t$, so $(e^{M(t)})' \ne M e^{M(t)}$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: I  think the answer is sill "yes", but the argument is more complicated.

Comment: @RobertLewis Ups! You are right. That you for come noting on it. Probably the easiest way to prove the result is to use the method of the majorant series.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre:  I think so.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: I think your thread is still workable, bur replace $M(t)$ by  its primitive $N(t)$ with $N(0)=I_{n\times n}$.